# Pyspin downloads on computer but not pycharm

Tags: python, pyspin

I have been trying to install PySpin in PyCharm. I am using Python 3.8 and followed the directions from the Spinnaker website and installed it on PyCharm through the terminal.

When I do pip list in PyCharm the spinnaker-python doesn't show up.
When I use pip list through the command prompt on Windows it does.
I am currently trying to run some code and when I try to run it the Error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySpin'" comes up.

I followed the installation instructions and the test example code worked from spinnaker when I attempted to run it through the terminal.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue and could help me?

Comment: Maybe PyCharm created a `venv` for you, which by default do not **inherit** from the `system site-package`, so you have either to create a new `venv` but **inherit** tunred on (possible in PyCharm) or to install `PySpin` in your venv.